# Is it possible to add Anno Domini mod into Steam distribution on Linux?

Tags: steam, mods, linux, mount-and-blade-warband

I have Linux (Lubuntu 16.04) and I play M&B Warband on Steam. I'd like to try the [Anno Domini mod](http://www.moddb.com/mods/anno-domini-1257), but I'm not sure how to add it to my game and if it's even possible with Steam distro and Linux.

So, is it possible? And if it is, then how should I do it (I've never used any mods before)?

I guess, that on Linux I can't use the .exe installer which can be downloaded from the link...

Comment: TIL that m&b works on linux

Answer (score 2):

Normally mods are playable, even if the installer is for Windows.
If that's the case you can use wine to install it.
For that you'll need to install wine and use the exe with it, or you install the mod under Windows.

`sudo apt-get install wine
wine [drag and drop the installer exe here]`

It's probably just a simple unzipper, so you should be able to target an empty directory inside your home directory, then copy those files correctly to your steam installation. Also make sure you only paste the location of the installer.

A little tip for the installer, if it asks you to choose the correct directory. Go to the steam directory, in /home/[yourname]/Steam/SteamApps/[nameofthegame]
And in this case make sure you're inside the Modules directory and then create a new directory so that your path looks like.

`Z:\home\[name]\Steam\SteamApps\common\[gamename]\Modules\1257AD`

Good luck.

Comment: So, you could use any compression tool to do that, something like 7zip would also work, right?

Comment: I don't know about his specific mod, but generally speaking yes.
There are also tools like cabextract, unshield and p7zip which allow you to extract those.